# What's the difference between camShift and cvCamShift?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

The camShift function of opencv c++ interface don't have the output parameter CvConnectedComp* comp and CvBox2D* box=NULL. What I can do to get these information if I use c++ interface camShift ? Can anybody please tell me how to do ? Thanks.

```
C++: RotatedRect CamShift(InputArray probImage, Rect& window, TermCriteria criteria);

C: int cvCamShift(const CvArr* prob_image, CvRect window, CvTermCriteria criteria, CvConnectedComp* comp, CvBox2D* box=NULL );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that you can retrieve connected component information; however, it already returns the information you need up to a RotatedRect. According to OpenCV [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html):

The function implements the CAMSHIFT object tracking algorithm [Bradski98]. First, it finds an object center using meanShift() and then adjusts the window size and finds the optimal rotation. The function returns the rotated rectangle structure that includes the object position, size, and orientation. The next position of the search window can be obtained with RotatedRect::boundingRect().

RotatedRect object has a following structure:

```
class RotatedRect
{
public:
    // constructors
    RotatedRect();
    RotatedRect(const Point2f& _center, const Size2f& _size, float _angle);
    RotatedRect(const CvBox2D& box);
    // returns minimal up-right rectangle that contains the rotated rectangle
    Rect boundingRect() const;
    // backward conversion to CvBox2D
    operator CvBox2D() const;
    // mass center of the rectangle
    Point2f center;
    // size
    Size2f size;
    // rotation angle in degrees
    float angle;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Now I understand the return value of cpp interface. But Rect& window parameter of this interface will be used for what ? It will give the target smallest bounding rectangle ? Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: According to documentation, it is just the initial window for searching. Docs:http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.0/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html